# How to cover lambda function in coverage kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, jacoco, android-jacoco

I am using jococo for test coverage. I want to cover every package, but I added this code

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class NoCoverageGenerated
```

to not excluded that class which I don't want to cover. But there is problem inside that class if we have any lambda function it not covering that lambda function. How can we cover lamda function ?

```
@NoCoverageGenerated
class ABC {
   
   private val OnSuccessListener: (any: Any?) -> Unit = { _ ->
      xyz()
   }
}
```